# Use setInterval() 2 times with same functions, but different parameters

Tags: javascript

Let's supose I have 2 labels in my frontend code which represents a timer each and they have to be updated every second. For that, I created one javascript function that does the job, which receives the actual DateTime and the label ID.

Now, I want to register the function to setInterval method twice, each with its own parameters. Any idea of why the following code isn't working?

```
(function () {
    function updateTimerLabel(label, currentDateTime) {
        currentDateTime.setSeconds(currentDateTime.getSeconds() + 1);
        label.text(currentDateTime.getHours().toString() + ":" + currentDateTime.getMinutes().toString() + ":" + currentDateTime.getSeconds().toString());
    }
    ;
    setInterval(function () { updateTimerLabel(label1, dateTime1); }, 1000);
    setInterval(function () { updateTimerLabel(label2, dateTime2); }, 1000);
}())
```

Comment: Any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ZWStv/.  (Assuming you are using jQuery)

Comment: Not so far, it was the first thing I checked. I was actually declaring a new dateTime inside parameters declaration, where I could have messed up with some syntax element. After I removed all the parameters to vars and passed them by their names, it worked just fine.

Comment: Can you please describe **how** it isn't working?  Does the method never fire at all, are there errors on the console, does the method fire but only for one and not the other... etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works just fine, I was messing up when declaring new objects in the parameters invocation. After I moved it out to external vars it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make two differently named functions; one for each label where they both simply call down to updateTimerLabel() with the proper parameters.

You are effectively resetting the first timer with the second call to setInterval since they have the same function name parameter.

Comment: That's precisely what I don't want to do, since I'd then have two methods which do the same thing.

The timer is not being reseted. That's what I thought that could be the root of the problem. I was declaring the parameters inside the calling function. After I moved them to outer variables, it worked just fine.